# Specific substring detection into a large string

Tags: r

I have this kind of data into a column in a character matrix. I would like to apply to the column V1 some grep function to detect "OK", "ERROR" or "NOISE" strings, and save them into a new column.

from img 1

```
"";"V1"
"img1";"19293.jpg : H344.8º : OK"
"img1";"19293.jpg : 9.6Kt : OK"
"img1";"19293.jpg : 44º31.449H'N : ERROR"
"img1";"19293.jpg : 2º31.238'W : OK"

"img2";"19294.jpg : H344.8º : OK"
"img2";"19294.jpg : 9.6Kt : OK"
"img2";"19294.jpg : 44º31.449H'N : NOISE"
"img2";"19294.jpg : 2º31.238'W : OK"

"img3";"19295.jpg : H344.8º : OK"
"img3";"19295.jpg : 9.6Kt : OK"
"img3";"19295.jpg : 44º31.449H'N : OK"
"img3";"19295.jpg : 2º31.238'W : OK"
```

...

until img n

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you mean three new columns, one each for OK, ERROR, and NOISE?

Comment: I see you are new to SO.  When you post data please make sure others can paste that data into R and run it.  Use `dput` (or `dput(head(x, 10))`) to make sure we can run your data easily.

Comment: Yeah, I´m new... Ok, I  will try to do that for the next time. Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read in your data file with

```
x <- read.table( "data.dat", sep = ";", header = TRUE )
```

Add column with the last word of `x$v1`

```
library( stringr )
x$extr <- word( x[,2], -1 )
x
      X                               V1  extr
1  img1         19293.jpg : H344.8º : OK    OK
2  img1           19293.jpg : 9.6Kt : OK    OK
3  img1 19293.jpg : 44º31.449H'N : ERROR ERROR
4  img1      19293.jpg : 2º31.238'W : OK    OK
5  img2         19294.jpg : H344.8º : OK    OK
6  img2           19294.jpg : 9.6Kt : OK    OK
7  img2 19294.jpg : 44º31.449H'N : NOISE NOISE
8  img2      19294.jpg : 2º31.238'W : OK    OK
9  img3         19295.jpg : H344.8º : OK    OK
10 img3           19295.jpg : 9.6Kt : OK    OK
11 img3    19295.jpg : 44º31.449H'N : OK    OK
12 img3      19295.jpg : 2º31.238'W : OK    OK
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 data$extracted <- gsub('^.*(OK|ERROR|NOISE)$|^.*$', '\\1', data$V1)
```

This makes sure that the strings you search for are retained, and an empty string is used otherwise.